# This worked last week(Qiskit library issue)

Tags: python-3.x, qiskit

This code used to work last week. I made sure that the pip install command is up-to-date and the right environment is set. I've been working on this code across windows and MacOS.... not the best idea but that may be part of the problem?

Why is it not working?

**note:** I blanked out the sensitive provider info... it's not really all Xs.

```
    import numpy as np
    from collections import defaultdict
    from qiskit import Aer
    from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
    from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
    from qiskit.algorithms import Grover, AmplificationProblem
    from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseOracle
    from qiskit.compiler import transpile
    from qiskit import assemble
    from qiskit import IBMQ
    from qiskit import execute
    from qiskit.tools import job_monitor
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    IBMQ.save_account('xxxxxxx', overwrite=True)
    IBMQ.load_account()
    provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='xxxx', group='xxxx', project='xxxx')
    device = provider.get_backend('ibmq_kolkata')
    circuit_list = []
    verification_list = []
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\qiskit\__init__.py in \__getattr__(self, attr)
    147             try:
--> 148                 from qiskit.providers import ibmq
    149 

~\anaconda3\envs\qc_env\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\__init__.py in <module>
     85 
---> 86 from qiskit.providers import BaseBackend, Backend  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
     87 

ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseBackend' from 'qiskit.providers' (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\qiskit\providers\__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MissingOptionalLibraryError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-63cbbaf81b4b> in <module>
     14 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     15 #import mapomatic as mm
---> 16 IBMQ.save_account('xxxxxxx', overwrite=True)
     17 IBMQ.load_account()
     18 #provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub = 'ibm-q')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\qiskit\__init__.py in \__getattr__(self, attr)
    150                 self.ibmq = ibmq.IBMQ
    151             except ImportError as ex:
--> 152                 raise MissingOptionalLibraryError(
    153                     "qiskit-ibmq-provider", "IBMQ provider", "pip install qiskit-ibmq-provider"
    154                 ) from ex

MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'qiskit-ibmq-provider' library is required to use 'IBMQ provider'. You can install it with 'pip install qiskit-ibmq-provider'."
```

Comment: also, I'm getting this warning whenever I pip install anything related to qiskit/jupyter notebook: WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iskit-terra (c:\users\ahmad\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages)

Comment: Nvm, solved it by deleting the distro that gave off the warning

Comment: Ended up uninstalling and installing Jupyter Notebook... works like a charm now

Comment: if you answered the question, then post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: a noob here; one needs an account id from ibmq?

Comment: @sAguinaga You do for their backend/provider. The simulators and fake quantum processors are free, so you can you just create a free profile on their website and get access to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Jupyter Notebook issue. Uninstalling and reinstalling it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, but reinstalling Jupyter Notebook did not help.
What helped, however, was the replacement of  `from qiskit import IBMQ` by `from  qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider`. This is the method recommended by IBM, and you can also get a message that the original version is depracted. Of the more significant changes is that you no longer make `IBMQ.load_account()`. Instead, setting up the backend should look like this:

```
IBMProvider.save_account(token, overwrite=True)
provider = IBMProvider()
backend  = provider.get_backend('ibmq_kolkata')
```